# White coating on bottom side of pepper leaves

Tags: indoors, diseases, peppers

I just noticed this white coating on the bottom side of a few leaves of my pepper plant. I can not wipe it off. Is this some kind of fungal disease or some pest?

[image]

Edit: I made some more images using a digital microscope. There is absolutely no movement visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer, I can see from the microscopic picture no mite damage.  Up close makes it look like a mold, like powdery mildew.  I would say if the rest of the plant is healthy I wouldn't worry about it too much at this point.   As long as the plant is healthy and growing new clean leaves, I would not be overly concerned.  I forgot to even ask if these are old or new leaves on the plant.